# Why NoSuchFieldError in eclipse, even provided required dependencies.?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, cxf, jakarta-migration

My project uses CXF JETTY JAKARTA

> CxfVersion=4.0.2
>
> JettyjVersion=11.0.15
>
> JacksonVersion=2.15.2

```
implementation ('com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs:jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider:${jacksonVersion}')
implementation ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${jacksonVersion}')
implementation ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonVersion}')
implementation ("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:${jacksonVersion}")
implementation ("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:${jacksonVersion}")
```

Above shows provided jackson artifacts in my gradle file. but it continuosly occure below error when I trying to run testCases.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.createContextual(EnumDeserializer.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:836)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:550)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:654)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._prefetchRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:2430)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.forType(ObjectReader.java:771)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:762)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1608)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:410)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:400)
```

Comment: You are compiling with a different version of Jackson from what you have at runtime. Check your dependencies. There's probably another dependency pulling in an older version. You can also check your runtime classpath using `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`.

Comment: Thanks your sugestion helps me to sort-out the issue